# No keyframes are visible but the object still moves

Tags: blender

I'm using Blender 2.8 and I just have 2 objects: `hand` and `gun` and I want to create animations for them. So, for instance, I want to create a simple firing animation. What I do:
1. I create animation for `gun`
2. I create animation for `hand`
But if I switch somehow incorrectly I "lose" the first animation I've created. I tried creating fake users and stuff. I just don't get why I select the armature for which I've just created the animation, it plays, but there are no keyframes.
Here's the [vid](https://youtu.be/bf-I1NeFVjI), here's the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GMzd6XQtj2DoC6tVzNVFg-KZVdppZ8XO/view?usp=sharing).
Ask me questions if you have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movement may be cached in Blender, you may need to reset the movement cache.

Alternatively, you should look at both the Track Controller and Dopesheet(action editor) - the animation may be stored in both.

The movement could be related to parenting ( to an object that is moving )

The movement could also be caused by physics simulation of a rigid body.

Hopefully with the help of the above, you find the problem.

Comment: I don't use any physics simulations though... Where can I find that Track Controller? I heard about it a lot, but I still don't get where is it

Comment: I had some animation data on my mesh that was conflicting with the data on the armature. Clearing the animation data on the mesh fixed the issue. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In the Animation mode (horizontal tabs across the top of the window), click on the object to animate.

The keyframes will appear.

If the object is not selected, the keyframes disappear.

Just leaving this here so that nobody spends 30 minutes trying to work this out, like i just did.